# how to prevent email clients add my images as attachments

Tags: html, html-email, email-templates

I am creating an html email template that will hopefully show on mostly used desktop and web email clients (such as Outlook, Gmail or Yahoo).

I'm having a hard time on doing an html email template where my images are being considered as attachments. I'm assuming it's possible to not show them as attachments since most websites that I am subscribed of such as Pinterest, they have images on their html email templates, but it doesn't show them as attachments too.

Here's a code I am testing

```
    <table align="center">
        <tbody>
            <tr>
                <td>
                    <table>
                        <tbody>
                            <tr>
                                <td>
                                <a href="http://www.taxq.io/signup"><img src="@web/mail/img/email-for-first-users-header.jpg" style="width:auto; height: auto; border-style: none; display: block;"/></a></td>
                            </tr>
                        </tbody>
                    </table>
                </td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>
                    <table>
                        <tbody>
                            <tr>
                                <td>
                                    <h2>Hi, non-user's name!</h2>
                                </td>
                            </tr>
                        </tbody>
                    </table>
                </td>
            </tr>
        </tbody>
    </table>
```

What I basically want to achieve is that, the email clients will not add my images on the attachments area.

Comment: Why not just link to them with the full path? <img src="http://www.example.com/image1.jpg" /> Then they will not show up as attachments

Answer (score -1):

Embedding an image in an email first requires that you have a version of said image as a base64 encoded string. Once your image is encoded, jump into your template, or whatever HTML you’re sending out, and embed it using a standard HTML image tag:

```
<img alt="My Image" src="data:image/jpeg;base64,/9j/4S/+RXhpZgAATU0AKgAAAAgACAESAAMAENkDZ5u8/61a+X...more encoding" />
```

Then you’re done! Send away.

Comment: you mean instead of the normal path for the image, i will add on the src attribute the base64 encoded string of the image?